# Query for a group of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use the simple query below to output a list of partIDs based on a modelID that we get from a printout on a sheet of paper.

We've always just used one modelId at a time like this:

```
   SELECT gm.partId, 343432346 as modelId
   FROM dbo.systemMemberTable sm
   WHERE gm.partID NOT IN (SELECT partID FROM systemsPartTable)
```

Is there a way to create a query that uses 10 modelIds at a time?

I can't think of a way because the modelIds are not in any table, just a printout that is handed to us.

Thanks!

Comment: what will be the desired output?each modelid with different part id or 1 part id with 10 modelid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT gm.partId, T.number as modelId
FROM ( values (4),(9),(16),(25) 
     ) as T(number) 
CROSS JOIN dbo.systemMemberTable sm
WHERE gm.partID NOT IN (SELECT partID FROM systemsPartTable)
```

op said getting an error but this is the test that runs for me

```
SELECT T.number as [modelID] 
      ,[main].[name]     
  FROM ( values (4),(9),(16),(25) 
       ) as T(number)  
  cross join [Gabe2a_ENRONb].[dbo].[docFieldDef] as [main] 
  where [main].[ID] not in (1)
```

Comment: i like the values approach +1.

Comment: @radar You can even SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ) AS MyTable(a, b);

Comment: I get an error? 'T' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Sorry T.number try again

Comment: It doesn't like T.number either : Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: You do know your question has a syntax error?  sm gm

Comment: oh it does? Where? Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

`insert` model ids into a table variable and then do the `join` with this table variable

Also use `not exists` instead of `not in` as not in doesn't work if there are `null` values in the parts table.

```
declare @modelIds table
(
model_id int
)

insert into @modelIds values (343432346) , (123456)
```

your select would be

As you want same model id repeated for all parts, you can just use `cross join`

```
   select gm.partId, m.model_id
   from dbo.systemMeberTable sm
   cross join @modelIds m 
   where not exists ( select 1 from systemPartsTable SPT where  SPT.partId = gm.PartID )
```

Comment: I don't have anything to join on though because systemMemberTable doesn't contain a modelID...just a partID.

Comment: @999cm999, you just won't report same part id against all model ids? then replace join with cross join and no need for ON condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ModelId INT);
INSERT INTO @T (ModelID)
VALUES (343432346), (343432347) -- And so on and so forth

SELECT gm.partId, T.ModelId
FROM dbo.systemMemberTable sm
INNER JOIN @T AS T
    ON T.ModelId = SM.ModelID
WHERE gm.partID NOT IN (SELECT partID FROM systemsPartTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Create table #tempmodelTable
(
  @modelid int
)
```

insert all modelid here, then use join with your select query

```
   INSERT INTO #tempmodelTable values(123123)
   INSERT INTO #tempmodelTable values(1232323)
   INSERT INTO #tempmodelTable values(1232343123)

   SELECT gm.partId, modelId
   FROM dbo.systemMemberTable gm inner join #tempmodelTable 
   WHERE gm.partID NOT IN (SELECT partID FROM systemsPartTable)
```